# Validate name to have no tabs or backslashes - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, validation

I have the validation below for my model:

```
validates_format_of :name, :with => /\A[\t\\]+\z/, :message => :'errors.backslash_or_tab'
```

The regex is checking for tabs and backslashes. 
The issue is that even if the name does not contain a tab or backslash, it does not pass the validation and I get the error message popping up.

Some example scenarios:

- testing123 - Fails (Expected to pass)
- backslash\ - Fails (Expected to fail)
- thisshouldwork  - Fails (Expected to pass)

Comment: It is matching only 1+ tabs or spaces. Can you add examples of the strings you are trying to validate to the question?

Comment: You need `/\A[^\t\\]+\z/` that will match a string that does not contain tabs and backslashes

Comment: @Thefourthbird
testing123 - Fails (Expected to pass)
backslash\ - Fails (Expected to fail)
thisshouldwork  - Fails (Expected to pass)

Comment: @DanielLawton Wiktor is right, you need to use a negated character class `[^` to match any char except a tab or backslash

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
Thanks for the help guys! Forgot I was looking to negate the characters!

Comment: I would write `str !~ /[\t\\]/`.